# Change one typed key for another

Tags: debian, keyboard, key-mapping

I have LUbuntu 13.04.

Is it possible to change the keyboard on the operating system, so that when I press <kbd>k</kbd> for instance, the system will hear it as I actually typed <kbd>m</kbd>?

Or any other key for that matter.

The thing is that the keyboard really isn't setup the way I would want to have it. If I could change the OS's keyboard then my efficiency would increase big time, especially in the long run as I could for instance, slowly evolve my keyboard towards a more efficient setting, such as Dvorak.

[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34582/terminal-change-keys)

Comment: Are you talking about the graphical interface or the text console? The answer depends on that.

Comment: The dream would be to get for both. Just an os overall keymap.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no solution that works uniformly for both console and GUI, so you have to change it twice. Use `loadkeys` to modify the console keyboard and `xmodmap` for the X11 keyboard. The details, in particular for `xmodmap`, depend a lot on which keys you want to modify – there are differences between regular keys and modifier keys like Ctrl or Alt.

Comment: Do you know any good guides on loadkeys?

Comment: No, I'm almost never using the console, so I never felt the need to change that. But it's a fairly common problem, so googling for "xmodmap dvorak" or "loadkeys dvorak" should be helpful.

Comment: I wouldn't really load Dvorak, I would start remapping the keys one after another as I see fit and as I see efficiency increasing possibilities. But thanks.